# Open URL from drop down list in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create a drop down list in PowerPoint where the user can open a selected web page.
For example can the drop down list contain two options:
1. Apple - opens apple.com
2. Microsoft - opens microsoft.com

I have managed to populate the drop down list, but not launch a browser based on the chosen option.

The slide will contain target KPIs for a company and the drop down list will contain the different plants. Based on the choice you can open a web based monitoring tool for that specific plant.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This will create an instance of Internet Explorer and navigate to the URL.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "www.microsoft.com"
```

You can assign the URL to a variable and use the variable as the argument for Navigate, e.g.

```
MS = "http://www.microsoft.com"
IE.Navigate MS
```

Comment: Or shell execute the URL to open it in the default browser rather than forcing MSIE.